# Why is Postman returning 500 internal error?

Tags: postman, web-api-testing

I require to hit an API using POST method having a csv file in the body.
However it is returning 500 internal error in postman.
What can be the causes for this . Does any firewall block api calls ?

Comment: Give examples of what you do, give your URL and data that you send.